# Pandas dataframe cdf of a column value with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

OK I have the following dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np
import seaboard as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,)), columns=['marks'])
```

Then I can plot the distribution of marks overall like this:

```py
sns.displot(data=df, x='length', kind='ecdf', hue='class')
```

Output:

[image]

Now I want a CDF of marks 45 and above .

```py
sns.displot(data=df, x=df['marks']>45, kind='ecdf')
```

[image]

I must be doing this wrong. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `df["marks"] > 45`, pandas will return this:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
      ...  
95    False
96     True
97    False
98     True
99    False
```

You can make this:

```
new_df = df[(df["marks"] > 45)]
sns.displot(data=new_df, kind='ecdf')
```